# Tableview reload not calling delegate methods in afnetworking success block?

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

```
-(void) refresh{

 manager = [[AFHTTPSessionManager...] iniwithBaseURL:...];

     [manager Get:... parameters:... success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject){
         //test success values in responseObject
         if(test){

             [self.tableView reloadData];
         }
     }
     ...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call it in

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
     [self.tableView reloadData];
});
```

Comment: Did you check that your self.tableView is not nil